# PHP string array variable: how to assign values

Tags: php, arrays, string

I guys, pretty new to php and I couldn't find this answer in the manual.
Basically if I have this situation:

```
$errors = array();
```

and I want to assign more than  string to $error, depending on which input filed I'm testing, how do I do? I know I can do this for the first one:

```
$errors[] = 'You must select a title';
```

and that saves the string in $errors[0]
But if afterwards I do:

```
$errors[] = 'Insert a first name';
```

what happens to the second string, is it saved in $error[1]?
thanks

Comment: Give it a go and see what happens when you echo the result with `print_r($errors);`

Comment: Also see the manual about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Expodax, "give it a go" is pretty difficult at the moment as..well long story :-) I won't be able to test it.

Comment: Rizier123, yes I had a look at the manual, as I said, and frankly it didn't help me

Comment: @jazzo You can use some online IDE's, e.g. https://3v4l.org/ , http://viper-7.com/ , https://ideone.com/ , http://eval.in/

Comment: @jazzo It's a simple array, there's even websites online that lets you execute simple php code.

Comment: This articles describes what the output is when adding to an array the way you show above: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p2.html

Comment: It is very difficult to learn a language when you can try it yourself, please install xampp or something ;)

Comment: thanks guuspor, exactly what I needed, clear now!
Interesting Rizier123, but all I needed was a quick answer rather than testing it myself.

Comment: @jazzo FYI you need to add a `@` before a name for them to get a ping. - That said, SO isn't a "quick answer machine", you're suppose to test and try before asking on SO.

Comment: I know @Epodax, but at the moment my hands are full, deadline is approaching and I thought I'd get a quick yes or no answer on SO, sorry. This saved me a lot of time and grief. And that's because I know almost nothing about php, but still I need to deliver...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you write:

```
$errors[] = 'something';
```

You push that value to the end of the Array.

[Here](http://ideone.com/uwbfeu) you have an example